# How to returns a map

Tags: javascript, async-await

I have this BooksDonation project with the following methods.

**The problem I'm having is with the third method (getAuthorsBookCount() ) I don't how to write it I should use map , can somebody help me.
And also can you check my code If it is okay or not.**

---

**getBook(bookName) :** Returns the book object if it exists, otherwise null

**getBooksWIthPageCountMoreThanX(pageCount)** :
Returns all the books that have a pageCount more than the given pageCount. Eg. If the user calls the function with pageCount=1000. It should return all the books that have pagecount >1000

**getAuthorBooks(author)** :
Returns all the books authored by that specific author.
Note: some books have more than one author. You should consider those too and return them as well.

**getAuthorsBookCount()**:
Returns a map that contains author name and a count of books their authored .

---

***BooksRepo Class***

```
class BooksRepo {
    constructor() {
        this.fse = require('fs-extra');
        this.catalogFilePath = '../data/catalog.books.json';
    }

    async readFileAsync(filePath) {
        let data = await this.fse.readFile(filePath);
        let parsedData = await JSON.parse(data);
        return parsedData;
    }

    async getBook(bookName) {
        let books = await this.readFileAsync(this.catalogFilePath);
        let book = books.find(b => b.title == bookName);
        return book;
    }

    async getBooksWIthPageCountMoreThanX(pagecount){
        let books = await this.readFileAsync(this.catalogFilePath);
        let book = books.find(b => b.pageCount > pagecount);
        return book;
    }

    async getAuthorBooks(author){
        let books = await this.readFileAsync(this.catalogFilePath);
        let book = books.find(b => b.authors.contains(author));
        return book;
    }

    async getAuthorsBookCount(){
        let books = await this.readFileAsync(this.catalogFilePath);
        let author = books.find(b => b.authors );
        return book;
    }

    async getBooksbyCatagory(category){
        let books = await this.readFileAsync(this.catalogFilePath);
        let book = books.find(b => b.categories == category);
        return book;

    }
}

module.exports = BooksRepo ;
```

***catalogFile: Example of how it structured***

```
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "title": "Unlocking Android",
    "isbn": "1933988673",
    "pageCount": 416,
    "publishedDate": {
      "$date": "2009-04-01T00:00:00.000-0700"
    },
    "thumbnailUrl": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/AKIAJC5RLADLUMVRPFDQ.book-thumb-images/ableson.jpg",
    "shortDescription": "Unlocking Android: A Developer's Guide provides concise...",
    "longDescription": "Android is an open source mobile phone platform based on the Linux operating ...",
    "status": "PUBLISH",
    "authors": [
      "W. Frank Ableson",
      "Charlie Collins",
      "Robi Sen"
    ],
    "categories": [
      "Open Source",
      "Mobile"
    ]
  },
```

Comment: You want to use `filter` not `map`. There's also a site on the exchange network specifically for [code-review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Adriani6 can you show me in code how to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert title author to map like this

```
const map = new Map();
  books.forEach((item)=>{
  if(item){
    const key = item.title;
    map.set(key,item.authors);
  }  });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    var authArray = [];
    var authCountArray = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < inputJson.length; i++) {
        authArray = inputJson[i].authors;
        for (let j = 0; j < authArray.length; j++) {
            authCountArray[authArray[j]] = ((authCountArray[authArray[j]] === undefined) ? 0 : authCountArray[authArray[j]]) + 1;
        }
    }

   //we can use it like this
    getAuthorsBookCount(authName){
        return authCountArray[authName];
    }
```